# JavaScript Script for Exploring a Website?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm trying to write a script that extract a database from a website.

The main page contains a table in which all lines contain a link to another page that contains the wanted database.

So far my script works for extracting the database from a specific line, but I don't know how to extend the script for all the lines of the table.

For example, once the database of the first line is extracted, my script should come back to the previous page, then click to the second line and extract the database:

```
var lastName = document.getElementById('A1').value; //extracting DB
if(_PGSAISIEBANCAIRE_SUB()){_JSL(_PAGE_,'A83','_self','','')} //going to previous page
document.getElementById('A23').click(); //going to the page of the next line
```

But when I run the script on the Google Chrome console, every time the page is reloaded, my script disappears so impossible to extract more that one line at a time.

Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `Does anyone have an idea?` tampermonkey

Comment: You should post whatever you have tried. That will help. And that way others can have a look at your code and guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it!

My problem was that for exploring the website I needed a loop in javascript and when I used the browser, after each page refrech my code disappeared.

The solution is to use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) (I used it on Python but it's possible with others languages) and to run javascript from your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://myWebSite.com")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('A40_2').click();")
```

You can easily perform Javascript loops by using Python:

```
for i in range (10):
    driver.execute_script("extract here;")
```

or with Javascript itself:

```
driver.execute_script("var i; for(i=0;i<10;i++){extract here;};")
```